# CPTPieChart change / turn off highlighted segment

Tags: ios, core-plot, pie-chart

It seems the default for a CPTPieChart is to highlight or offset from the rest of the chart the largest segment.

I would like to turn this highlighting / offset off or perhaps change which one is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *default* is no offset for any pie slice. If you implement one of the following datasource methods, you can provide offset values for any or all slices. Return zero (0) for a given index to indicate no offset for the corresponding slice.

```
-(NSArray *)radialOffsetsForPieChart:(CPTPieChart *)pieChart recordIndexRange:(NSRange)indexRange;
-(CGFloat)radialOffsetForPieChart:(CPTPieChart *)pieChart recordIndex:(NSUInteger)idx;
```

Comment: Damn, had that implemented but didn't realise.